# Google Sheets - Form - Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, scripting, google-forms

copy paste script
Hi, I am using a script I found on here, I have no idea on scripting so please forgive me if I am being thick. The script copies from google sheets Form Responses 1 to Responses and inserts in column K every time the form is submitted this works fine.

However I have formulas in columns A-J and the script will not past into these rows as they are not blank - is there anyway to change the script so it will ignore if anything is in Columns A-J - script below and link to demo spreadsheet.

```
    function onSubmit(e) {
const range = e.range;
const srcSheet = range.getSheet();
const dstSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Responses");
const srcRange = srcSheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 1, 1, srcSheet.getLastColumn());
const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 11);
srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, {contentOnly: true});
```

https://forms.gle/ijxiSnh6VE7eLm4i6

The script works but if there are formulas in A-J it will skip that row and past into the next free row

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these methods:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  const srcSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const dstSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Responses");
  const vs = srcSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
function onSubmit(e) {
  const dstSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Responses");
  let o = e.values.slice();
  o.shift();//remove timestamp
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1 , o.length).setValues([o]);
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [onFormSubmit(e) Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: they both work but I got rows and columns confused - so what i need is the data pasted to column K - i have formulas in columns A to J so they are not blank. Your solution above works fine but it looks for the next blank row can it be changed so it only looks for blank rows from column K?

Comment: If you can provide a table of data that I can use to implement your desired changes that would be helpful.  Please note I do not follow links to offsite resources.